# How to use the Windows "hook function" with Perl Win32::GUI?

Tags: perl, winapi, user-interface, hook

I am working on Windows XP SP 3, Strawberry Perl.
I would like to let the user of my Perl program select a file; but when using Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName(), I would like the Windows file selection dialog to open in the "Details" file list option, and not in the default "List" file list option.

Googling on the Net, it seems that I have to use the Windows "hook" function, and send certain messages to the file selection control. The documentation about that is MSDN, and I don't seem to master how to apply it in Perl.

Can anyone recommend what should be the right call syntax in Perl?

Here is my code sample, where the file selection dialog opens with the (default) "List" option:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use 5.014;    
 use Win32::Console;
 use Win32::GUI();
 use autodie; 
 use warnings    qw< FATAL  utf8     >;
 use Carp::Always;
 use Win32API::File::Time qw{:win};
use Image::ExifTool qw(:Public);
use Date::Parse;

# ...
my ( $FileName, $ImageDir, $DIR, $TopDir);
# ...
$TopDir = 'D:\My Documents';
    $ImageDir = Win32::GUI::BrowseForFolder( -root => $TopDir, -includefiles => 1,);
    unless ($ImageDir) { 
        say '$DirName not defined after calling Win32::GUI::BrowseForFolder, ',
        'Photo date set line'.__LINE__;
        exit;
    }
    else {
        say "Identified directory: $ImageDir";
    }    
    # now select a file

    $FileName = Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName( -title  => 'Select an image file', -directory => $ImageDir,
        -file   => "\0" . " " x 256,
        -filter => ["Image files (*.jpg)" => "*.jpg;*.jpeg", "All files", "*.*", ],);
    unless ($FileName) {
        say '$FileName not defined after calling Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName, ',
        'Photo date set line'.__LINE__;
    }
    else {
        say "Identified image file: $FileName";
    }
# ...
```

Note: (somewhat) similar post at: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=989418

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the `Win32::GUI` API exposes neither the `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` flag bit or the `lpfnHook` field of the `GetOpenFileName` options.

You could perhaps get it working using the `Win32::API` module to work at an even lower level, but you would have to build the entire `OPENFILENAME` structure yourself using `pack` and write some XS code for the hook handler.

Comment: Thank you, Borodin. Is this connected to it?  - Would it help?: http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=reference-methods#hook

Comment: @Helen: That is related, but it is for attaching a hook to a window whose handle you have access to. When you call `GetOpenFileName`, a dialogue box is created, manipulated by the user, and closed again before control is returned to the calling program with information about which file was selected. So the main program isn't running while the dialogue box appears and it can't get and use a window handle. That is why you need to specify a callback, which would be sent the `WM_INITDIALOG` message saying that the dialogue box was about to be displayed and allowing it to make any final adjustments